# SQL Exception : Unexpected Token - UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to create a new MS Access table from a Java program. The SQL query is below. I get an error saying:

> net.UcanacessSQLException:UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected token: REQ-MTI

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt;

String createStmt = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] ([Test_Case_ID] CHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY, [Test_Name] CHAR (120)," 
    + " [Test_Description] CHAR (100), [Req-MTI] CHAR (15), [Req-Card_ID] CHAR (50), [Req-H19] CHAR (20));";

prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(createStmt);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();
```

I can't use underscores instead of the hyphen. I've tried putting all the table names in square brackets, quotations, ect, but nothing seems to be working. I've taken the generated string and pasted it into a MS Access query and it creates the table fine there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the full code please?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: can you please use `Req_MTI` instead of `Req-MTI`

Comment: Sorry, should have put in the question that I can't use underscores.

Comment: you already use the it in `Test_Case_ID` i assume that names with `-` is not accepted so please remove it

Comment: I understand that, however the specifications I'm using require some of the names to have hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sort-of reproduce your issue under UCanAccess 4.0.2. It seems to be getting confused by the spaces following the `CHAR` keyword. I could get the code to run if I specified the fields as, e.g., `CHAR(20)` instead of `CHAR (20)`.

Edit re: question update

I was able to reproduce the issue under UCanAccess 4.0.1. The workaround is to use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement` to execute the DDL. (It's not even necessary to remove the spaces as described above, at least under 4.0.1.)

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error. I do feel like it is an issue on the UCanAccess side.

Comment: @theKD - Note that I said "sort-of reproduce". The repro code in your question is clearly not what you're actually using because it doesn't even compile: your `createStmt` declaration is malformed. Please fix the code in your question. (Hint: Copy-and paste is your friend.)

Comment: It is the code that I used, the `createStmt` is malformed because StackOverflow is forcing line breaks. The only line breaks should be before the `+`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

***If column names contain any characters except letters, numbers, and underscores, the name must be delimited by enclosing it in back quotes (`)***

so try changing your column name to :

```
`Req-MTI`
```

Comment: Hi, I've change to back quotes, however I still get the same error.